# execl in child process works for only in specific cases

Tags: c++, bash, pipe, fork, execl

I have been bussy for the last five hours with this problem so I hope someone can help me out. In my C++ program (which I develop in QTcreator on lubuntu) I want to run airodump-ng in the child process of my program. The output of airodump-ng should be directed to the STDOUT of the parent proces. This works with many other programs but strangly enough not with airodump-ng. There is simply no output in the console. This, or my Linux crashes, I get logged out and when I log back in all my programs are closed. Does anybody know why?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    //execl("/usr/sbin/airodump-ng", "airodump-ng", (char*)0 );
    //dup2(1, 2); //pipe stderr to stdout

    pid_t pidAirodump;
    pid_t pidAircrack;
    int pip[2];

    if (pipe(pip) < 0) {
        perror("allocating pipe for child input redirect");
        return -1;
      }

    pidAirodump = fork();
    if(pidAirodump > 0)//parent
    {
        pidAircrack = fork();
        if(pidAircrack == 0)//pidAircrack
        {
            close(pip[0]);
            dup2(pip[1], 2);
            cout << "test" << endl;

            //execl("/usr/sbin/arp", "arp", (char*)0 );
             execl("/usr/sbin/airodump-ng", "airodump-ng ", "mon0", (char*)0 );
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else//pidAirodump
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few oddities in your program. But let's start at the question - you should distinguish between `execl` not working and the program you're trying to execute is misbehaving. You should not be able to crash linux from a user space program without special privilieges. The code snippet you've posted should not do that (what `airpodump-ng` does is another question).

If `execl` fails it will return and set `errno`, I suggest that you examine that after `execl` instead of just `exit`ing.

Now for the oddities:

The first `fork`? Why do you do that? You basically `fork`s and `exit`s the child right away. You `fork` again and let the parent `wait` - this should trigger on the fact that the first child has terminated rather immediately.

The `pipe`, why do you do that if you wan't to keep the standard out? Instead you `dup` standard err to the write end of the pipe, but you doesn't seem to do anything with the read end.